# Find the roots of a function with logarithms (possibly using lambert W function)

Tags: logarithms, roots, lambert-w

I am wondering if anyone can help me find an analytical solution to the roots of the following function:
$$f(b) = c\log \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + (n-c)\log \left( \frac{1-b}{1-a} \right),$$
$a,b \in (0,1)$ and  $n,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $c \le n$.

I have done some googling and I found references to using lambert's w function for finding roots in situations where logs are involved; unfortunately, nothing I've read seems like it will solve my problem. I am admittedly completely new to lambert's w function, so it's very possible that I am missing something.

I have proven $f(b)$ is concave and only has two roots ([graphical](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+C+log+%28b%2Fa%29+%2B+%28N-C%29+log+%28%281-b%29%2F%281-a%29%29+where+a+%3D+0.1%2C+N+%3D+10%2C+C+%3D+4%2C+b+between+0+and+1) support for this claim).  Clearly one root is $b=a$, the other root is my challenge.  The context of the actual problem--which I can expound upon if it would be helpful--leads me to believe that this non-trivial root (r) should be a function of $t = \frac{c}{n}$, i.e., $r = h(t)$.

I am open to any ideas or suggestions, even if they do not exactly solve the problem, because they may provide analytical approximations or bounds on $h$ and/or $h^{-1}$, which is my ultimate goal.

### Update

@Claude's suggestion to taylor expand moves us forward because we can get a 2-degree polynomial approximation: $$f(b) = f(b_{*}) + \frac{f''(b_{*})(b-b_{*})^2}{2}+R_2(b),$$ where $R_2(b)$ is the remainder/error. We can then use the quadratic equation to find the roots of this 2-degree polynomial, but can we **get a bound on $R_2(b)$.**

#### Why Bound The Remainder (Context of My Problem)

So $f(b)$ is a concave function, with 2 roots: trivially when $b = a$ and another non-trivial root that I will call $b_{\max}$. The function $f$ is maximized at $b_{*} = \frac{c}{n}$, i.e., $b_{*} = \arg\max_b f(b)$.  I originally wanted to find $b_{\max}$ because I believe there is some other function $h(b_{*}) = b_{\max}$.  I believe from this function I should be able to derive an inequality in the vein of $b_{*} \le \frac{b_{\max}}{q}$, where $q$ is a real number or possibly a function of other variables.  Intuitively, $b_{\max}$ cannot be "too close" to $b_{*}$.

By doing the taylor expansion approximation as suggested, we will get an approximation of $f$ (called $f_{\text{aprx}}$). From $f_{\text{aprx}}$, we can get an approximation for $b_{\max}$, (called $b_{\text{aprx}}$). However, we need to bound how far away $b_{\text{aprx}}$ is from $b_{\max}$. This is because once we compute our approximation of $h$ (called $h_{\text{aprx}}$)--from deriving the relationship between $b_{*}$ and $b_{\text{aprx}}$ in $f_{\text{aprx}}$--we then compute $b_{*} \le \frac{b_{\text{aprx}}}{q_\text{aprx}}$. However, I need to get a bound on how far away $q_{\text{aprx}}$ if from $q$, which means I need a bound on how far away $b_{\text{aprx}}$ is from $b_{\max}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can have an explicit solution and I am afraid that numerical methods should be required.

We have  $$f(b) = c\log \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + (n-c)\log \left( \frac{1-b}{1-a} \right)$$ $$f'(b)=\frac{c-b n}{b(1-b)}$$ $$f''(b)=-\frac{nb^2 -2 cb +c}{(b-1)^2 b^2}$$ Since $c<n$, $f''(b)$ is always negative (as you prooved it). The first derivative cancels at $b_*=\frac cn$.

What I should do is to expand $f(b)$ around $b_*$ and make the approximation $$0=\left(c \log \left(\frac{c}{a n}\right)+(n-c) \log \left(\frac{n-c}{(1-a) n}\right)\right)+\frac{n^3
   }{2 c
   (c-n)}\left(b-\frac{c}{n}\right)^2+O\left(\left(b-\frac{c}{n}\right)^3\right)$$ Solve for $b$ (retaining the largest root. From this point, start Newton method.

As you suggested, the equation simplifies if you set $n=tc$ from the beginning and the approximate solution just depends on $a$ and $t$.

Applied to the case you gave $(a=0.1, n=10, c=4)$, the pproximation gives an estimate $\approx 0.786516$ for a solution which is $\approx 0.768991$.

Comment: Thanks @Claude for the response, taylor expanding is a great idea. I actually found your responses in another related [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253919/solution-of-a-lambert-w-function) which uses the quadratic equation to find the roots of the taylor expanded 2-degree polynomial.  Since I can only get an approximate solution, I really need to get a (upper and lower) bound on the remainder. I've been searching on how to do this, but still have not been able to do this in the context of this problem, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add another answer to this problem rather than to edit the previous one.

Setting $n=tc$ in the previous equation, we then have $$f(b)=\log \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+(t-1) \log \left(\frac{1-b}{1-a}\right)$$ $$f'(b)=\frac{1-b t}{b(1-b)}$$ $$f''(b)=-\frac{tb^2 -2 b+1}{b^2(1-b)^2}$$ The maximum of the function occurs at $b=\frac 1t$ and the second derivtive is always negative since $t>1$.

Now, let us define a second point $b_*$ such that $$f'(b_*)=-f'(a)$$ $b_*$ is the solution of the quadratic $$ (a t-1)b^2+ \left(a^2 t-2 a t+1\right)b+a(1-a) =0$$ and the root $b_*$ must selected such that $b_*>\frac 1t$.

Now, apply one iteration of Newton or Halley or Householder methods starting at $b_0=b_*$. This should give a good estimate of the solution; if, by chance, $f(b_*)<0$, the first iteration of Newton method would provide an upper bound of the solution (Darboux theorem).

Using the values you gave $a=0.1$, $t=2.5$ the first iterate of the three methods mentioned above are $ 0.784510$, $0.772058$ and $0.769675$ while, as said earlier, the solution is $0.768991$

Comment: Firstly, I may instead set $n = \frac{c}{t}$, which means the maximum occurs at $b=t$; otherwise, this sounds like a good solution. Secondly, the success of this will all depend on if the root to the taylor expansion polynomial ($b_{\ast}$) satisfies $f\left(b_{\ast}\right) < 0$ . This does introduce the idea of if there is a way to generate a 2-degree concave polynomial that is guaranteed to have it's second root greater (but still close to) a non-polynomial concave's function's second root, assuming the function has a second root.